# What is the best way to track multi language projects in Git?

Tags: git, repository-design

I work with automation solutions that leverage anywhere from 2-4 different languages for a single project. For example, I might use C# to manage the overall automation and the user interface but this will talk to a PLC as well as to a robotic arm each containing their own code base.

My team and I store each of these code bases using git but each code base is under its own repository. This means managing 1-4 different repositories for a single project solution in which someone might have to clone all 4 just to get one automation solution up and running. I would like to bring these all under one umbrella within git but wondering if there are some good arguments for keeping things broken out like this.

Has anyone run into this and how do you recommend handling unique projects in git that contain multiple programming languages?

Answer (score 0):

This would be generally managed under a parent project with the 4 subrepos declared [as submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

That way, you can clone all 4 repos in one command:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules /url/parent/repo
```